# In React, can I use the set function of useState outside of a functional component?

Tags: reactjs

In React, can I use the set function of useState outside of a functional component?

```js
const WhatEver:React.FC = function() {

  const [num, setNum] = React.useState(0);
  
  return <>{num}</>;
  
}

export function changeNum(num) {

  setNum(num); //Can I use it here, is there any way?
  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to call the function in the scope it is defined in, but that's not react related, that's javascript.

You can also pass the function as a prop to a child component and use it there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The `changeNum` function currently has no way of knowing what `setNum` is. One  way to solve this is to pass setNum as an argument.

```
export function changeNum(num, setNum) {
  setNum(num);
}
```

Another way is to define the function within the component.

```
const WhatEver:React.FC = function() {

  const [num, setNum] = React.useState(0);
  function changeNum(num) {
      setNum(num);
    }
  
  return <>{num}</>;
  
}
```